# Program unable to read from file and save to variable

Tags: java, file, variables

When I run my code it says that there is an InputMismatchException? Works for the two first read-lines, but hwne I try to read the int and double-lines it doesn't and the string-line doesn't actually read anything into the variable, it is empty as it doesn't print anything at the system.out.println(a +b)... Any tips?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Uke55{
    public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    try{
        PrintWriter utfil=new PrintWriter(new File("minfil55.txt"));
        utfil.println('A');
        utfil.println("Canis familiaris betyr hund");
        utfil.println(15);
        utfil.printf("%.2f", 3.1415);
        utfil.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        Scanner innfil=new Scanner(new File("minfil55.txt"));
        char a=innfil.next().charAt(0);
        String b=innfil.nextLine();
        System.out.println(a +b);
        int c=(int)innfil.nextInt();
        double d=(double)innfil.nextDouble();
        innfil.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are trying to parse a value that exceeds the integer range. See [InputMismatchException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html)

Comment: Please, always post the exact error message (and the relevant part of the StackTrace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you use next(), nextInt(), and nextDouble(), it doesn't go to a new line. **Only newLine() moves the cursor to the next line.** Do this:

```
try{
    Scanner innfil=new Scanner(new File("minfil55.txt"));
    char a=innfil.nextLine().charAt(0); //first error was here. calling next() only
                                        //read A and not the \r\n at the end of the 
                                        //line. Therefore, the line after this one was 
                                        //only reading a newline character and the 
                                        //nextInt() was trying to read the "Canis" line.
    String b=innfil.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println(a +b);
    int c=(int)innfil.nextInt(); 
    innfil.nextLine(); //call next line here to move to the next line.
    double d=(double)innfil.nextDouble();
    innfil.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**next(), nextInt(), nextDouble(), nextLong(), etc... all stop right before any whitespace (including the end of a line).**

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have in file:

```
A\n
Canis familiaris betyr hund\n
15\n
3.14
```

Where `\n` represents new line character.

When you call first time

```
innfil.nextLine().charAt(0)
```

it reads `A`, and scanner reading points to first `\n`

Then you call

```
innfil.nextLine()
```

it reads till `\n` (`nextLine()` reads till `\n` and puts scanner reading pointer past `\n`), and makes reading pointer past `\n`. Reading pointer will be at `C` in next line.

Then you call

```
innfil.nextInt()
```

duh! scanner can't recognize `Canis` as integer, input mismatch!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on **[Scanner.nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)** it
"*Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.*"

So, after calling `char a=innfil.next().charAt(0);` the "cursor" is at the end of the first line. Calling `String b=innfil.nextLine();` reads until the end of the current line (where there is nothing left to read) and advances to the next line (where the actual String is).

**Solution**
You need to advance to the next line before calling `String b=innfil.nextLine();`:

```
...
char a=innfil.next().charAt(0);
innfil.nextLine();
String b=innfil.nextLine();
...
```

***Note***:
Although **[Scanner.nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29)** and **[Scanner.nextDouble()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29)** behave the same way as **[Scanner.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29)**, you don't face the same problem, because those methods will read the next complete token (where "*A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern*") and white-space characters (such as newline-characters) are considered delimiters. So, those methods will automatically advance to the next line if needed, in order to find the next *complete token*.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check something is actually written to your file? I doubt that. Try calling flush() before you close your PrintWriter. EDIT: sorry I was wrong here because I was thinking of the auto line flush.

Comment: Of course I did... That's why I could say which of the lines did work and which didn't.